# Foreign key related to self. Creating an instance

Tags: django-models

I have a Foreign key that relates to self

```
class Fok(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
  fok = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='foks')
```

trying to create a first instance of this class ending up with an error: fok.fok_id can not be NULL.
Where do I mistake? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first instance doesn't have a related `fok`, therefore you must allow `null` values in this relation.

```
fok = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='foks', null=True)
```